# Java HashMap Iterate Each Var and Return Value: Boolean boolean , Integer int error?

Tags: java, android, integer, hashmap, boolean

```
HashMap<String, Boolean> mAchBools = new HashMap<String, Boolean>(){{
    put("myBool1", false);
    }
};

HashMap<String, Integer> mAchInts = new HashMap<String, Integer>(){{
    put("myInt1", 0);
    }
};

boolean isEmpty() {
    for (boolean b : mAchBools.values()) if (b) return false;
    for (int i : mAchInts.values()) if (i != 0) return false;           
    return true;            
}
```

I create a HashMap will Booleans and a HashMap with Integers. Now I want a method to check and see if the values are "empty" (all booleans are false and all integers are 0).

I run Debugger and I can see that my boolean in the Hashmap is false, but my method "isEmpty" still returns false.

Why does my "isEmpty" check fail? I think it's a difference between boolean and Boolean but I'm not sure.

Comment: May be your 2nd map contained an integer value not equal to `0`?

Comment: I wouldn't use primitives when looping over `Map` values as they can be `null`, this will then throw an NPE.

Comment: The code you provided here returns `true` on my pc, under Ubuntu using Eclipse to test.

Comment: @Boris, How would I NOT use primitives in this case?

Comment: Use `Integer` and `Boolean`. This isn't your problem but isn't a bug waiting to happen.

Comment: @Selzier Boris is referring to the primitives in your isEmpty method

Comment: Returns true on my machine (OSX, Java 7). Did you save your source file and recompile your class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java automatically converts between Boolean <> boolean and int <> Integer.  So your code is technically correct as written.

Comment: This is totally untrue, you can use `Boolean` and `boolean` interchangeably (for the most part).